# How do I get an attribute value where another attribute is equal to x?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div where I want to pull information from a name tag based on the index value of that container. Is this possible?

For example

```
<div name="value I want" data-index="3">
```

So I know the index number, I want the name value, to use in a java-script function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are use Jquery, the code below is the correct way

```
var name = $("div[data-index=3]").attr("name");
console.log("value = " + name);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) to target one attribute and then access the other attribute from the result

```
    var div = document.querySelector("[data-index=\"3\"]");
    console.log(div.getAttribute("name"));
```